# How to connect to either one of multiple elasticsearch cluster at runtime depending on request?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I am currently using

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and following dependency for elasticsearch

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I am connecting to single elastic cluster now, but now I need to connect to either of the multiple elasticsearch clusters. This should happen at runtime using spring cloud config. Can this be achieved and how?

Comment: Can you please share the code for how you've connected for a single instance?